# Linux: How to setup the environment for React Native correctly?

Tags: linux, react-native

Sorry for bothering you with my problems, but it has become a little bit weird ...

Meanwhile, it looks as if my problems were not really caused by this "Android virtual device (unavailable)" I decribed in my previous post ...

In the meantime, I'm relatively sure that all my problems were caused by the user rights ...

By mounting my partition in /etc/fstab by Device ID with the option values

```
gid=users,fmask=133,dmask=022,umask=007,locale=en_US_UTF8
```

the message "Permission denied" from yesterday disappeared (see below) after executing

```
npx react-native start
```

But when I tried to start my app using

```
npx --debug react-native run-android
```

this occurs

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:processResources'.
> Could not copy META-INF to '/windows/D/02 Web/02 Javascript/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/build/resources/main/META-INF'.
   > Could not set file mode 755 on '/windows/D/02 Web/02 Javascript/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/build/resources/main/META-INF'.
```

It says that the file mode cannot be set ... there must be another problem with my option values. Any idea?

All these problems appeared after buying a new computer ... on the new computer, this development partition is located on a primary partition of a SSD, on my old pc, it was an extended partition on a HDD ... but that cannot be the cause? My development partition is an NTFS partition, could that be the cause?

I created a React native project in my user home directory, there were no such access problems?

Any idea what's wrong with the user rights I indicated? Or maybe the best way is to format my development partition to BTFS?

Thanks a lot in advance for your efforts, and kind regard, Frank

=====

I'm trying to learn React Native on my new computer using a linux system (Open Suse Leap 15.4).

I think the problems mentioned below are caused by the user rights.

I created an NTFS partition and mounted it in /etc/fstab by UUID with the option values

```
users,uid=my_user_name,gid=users,fmask=133,dmask=022,umask=007
```

Those rights are different from those below, and I got a different error message

```
...@localhost:/windows/D/02 Web/02 Javascript/AwesomeProject> npx react-native start
sh: /windows/D/02 Web/02 Javascript/AwesomeProject/node_modules/.bin/react-native: Permission denied
```

The rights for my development partition must be wrong ... but what can I do to make this work? Any ideas?

Best wishes, Frank

=======

I'm trying to set up my React Native development environment as described
[here at https://reactnative.dev/][1]
on a Linux OS (Suse Leap 15.4).

Comment: what is your jdk version? https://www.techspot.com/downloads/5553-java-jdk.html downloaded here jdk maybe you downlow zip file you want to download exe file

Comment: @GattuPatel , first of all thanks for your answer.

I don't think this is caused by the jdk - as I installed Android Studio in November, all was fine, but in the meantime I bought a new computer. 

There seems to be some kind of problem with Android Studio setup, see here [https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/108axki/in_android_studio_setup_wizard_it_says_android/], posted on reddit a few days ago.

I also received "Android virtual device (unavailable)", as mentioned there ... any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: see here full setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7xdbsjFGtU&t=1579s hope this will help you!!

Comment: @GattuPatel , thanks again. I'm not very experienced with React Native - this course from Youtube seems to be very good. I observed the reddit post during the past days, there seems to be a real problem with the Android Studio setup routine ...

I'd like to wait a little, maybe this problem will fixed ...

Comment: I wish I wouldn't have bought a new computer :) Last year, in November, all worked fine. The solution mentioned on reddit doesn't work. I think I'm going to turn to Java, because I'm a little bit more experienced with it ... anyone else who has a proposal how to deal with this "Android virtual device (unavailable)"? This must be the cause ...

Comment: may be some problem with your pc so just restart and do it again

Comment: Yes, it must be a problem with the pc ... it must be caused by the user rights, I modified my question.